# Power Bi measure: Find average total spend for each ID

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a measure in Power Bi that finds the average of the total_spend for each ID. My table looks like this:

| ID | Total_Spend |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | £34.00 |
| 1234 | £34.00 |
| 1234 | £ 34.00 |
| 4325 | £ 56.00 |
| 4325 | £ 56.00 |
| 4325 | £ 43.00 |
| 4325 | £ 43.00 |
| 5678 | £ 12.00 |
| 5678 | £ 12.00 |

I've tried:

```
AvgIDSpend=
AVERAGEX (
SUMMARIZE (
Table,
Table[ID],
"Total Average", SUM( DISTINCT ( Table[Total_spend] )
),
[Total Average]
)
```

But got this error- *The SUM function only accepts a column reference as an argument.*

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do it would be to just create a measure that calculate the average of `Table[Total_spend]`, and then use it in a table visual alongside `Table[ID]`.

First, the measure :

```
Avg_Total_spend =
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(Table[Total_spend])
)
```

Then, you create a new table visual with columns:

- `Table[ID]`
- `Table[Avg_Total_spend]`

Or, as a table expression :

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Table,
        Table[ID]
    ),
    "Average Table_spend",
    Table[Average_Table_spend]
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me the average spend across all ID's, not each one. So when I put it on a table I get the same average for every ID

Comment: Using the example data you've provided I do not reproduce the behaviour you've just described. I get a different average for each ID, as expected. [Caption](https://i.imgur.com/tDLSEL3.jpg)